# extjs gridfilter icon not showing in IE but shows in Firefox

Tags: extjs

In Gridfilters, if you are using a StringFilter field, then there is a property in StringFilter.js called :

```
icon: 'ux-gridfilter-text-icon',
```

Basically this loads a 'binocular' icon in beside the filter text box. This works fine with mozila, but with IE, the icon is not showing up.
Is this a known problem by any chance?
I am using the source at : http://ccinct.com/lab/filter-grid/
My ext js ver is 3.2.1
The girdfilters version seems to be v0.2.7 as per GridFilters.js
EDIT: This works in Chrome fine. Just IE is the problem
EDIT#2: Also , the other css properties like column headers etc are fine. it is with the loading of the image that there is a problem.

Comment: Please provide some inputs as to what I should try. I tried:1.Giving absolute url of img in css file.2.putting !important in the css.

Comment: FYI the icon shows ok in IE9 RC

Comment: I've tried IE7, IE8 and IE9 document modes and browser modes in IE9 and I can't seem to replicate this issue. What version of IE are you using? Is the placeholder there for the image and it's just not loading?

Comment: if you have solved your problem, you might want answer your own question, in case others come up with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. it got solved.
I had taken the filters plugin (ux,resources) folders, and distributed the files in diff packages in my web application.
For some reason, that messed up things even though the references were all correct. When I started using the package as it was given, it got solved.
Not sure why though.