# How to debug css in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there a way to debug a css file in IE? I wish to see if a particular background-image is loaded or not.
This is in reference to the question:
[extjs gridfilter icon not showing in IE but shows in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035331/extjs-gridfilter-icon-not-showing-in-ie-but-shows-in-firefox)

Comment: In  IE8, you can press F12 to get a Firebug-like tool that's pretty good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or for any version of IE, try [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). You can simply bookmark the link given on that page (bookmarklet) and then, to open a FireBug like thingy whilst on IE, simply click on the bookmark you just added.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in browser troubleshooting tool (aka Developer Toolbar) by pressing F12.

It is built into IE8 and later, but you can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) and install it in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to target IE specifically in your CSS? If so I wrote a blog post about this not so long ago, please have a read: http://ajthomas.co.uk/blog/?p=299.